# Laravel 10.x cast query parameters to correct types before reaching controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `GET` endpoint that accepts a boolean `active` and an integer `ID` as a query parameter. Something like `GET /stuff?active=1&ID=10`.

Neither of these parameters are required.

If I were to do `GET /stuff?active=1` and would try to retrieve the value from the `Request` by doing `$request->get('active')` I would get a value of `1` as a string.

If having `declare(strict_types=1)` enabled and a method in a service such as

```
public function getBy(bool $active = null) {
   ...
}
```

And calling the method in a `Controller` for example

```
 $controllerMethod->getBy($request->get('active'))
```

would result in `Argument #0 ($active) must be of type ?bool, string given` which is obviously not good.

Now my question: **Is there a way to cast the request parameters prior to them reaching the `Controller`? Perhaps in a `FormRequest` class somehow?**

I'm well aware I can do `$request->has('active') ? $request->get('active') : null` in the `Controller` but this is just extra clutter that I would like to move somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outsourcing that to a *FormRequest* class should be working with either:

```
/**
 * Handle a passed validation attempt.
 */
protected function passedValidation(): void
{
    $this->replace(['active' => (bool)$this->active]);
}
```

or by doing the same even before validation inside:

```
protected function prepareForValidation(): void
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation)

Comment: I like this approach, although in my case I'd have to do `if($this->query->has('active')) {
            $this->query->set('active', $this->query->getBoolean('active')); }` since I don't know if the param actually exists. `replace` will not work for me since I have a `application/json` content type and unfortunately that takes precedence over `query` parameter bag.

Answer (score 1):

1 way (getter)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * @property-read ?string $active
 */
class MyRequest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        // TODO: implement it
    }

    public function getActive(): bool 
    {
        return (bool)$this->query('active');
    }
}

// $controllerMethod->getBy($request->getActive());
```

2 way (override)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * @property-read bool $active
 */
class MyRequest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        // TODO: implement it
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function prepareForValidation(): void
    {
        $this->merge([
            'active' => (bool)$this->query('active'),
        ]);
    }
}

// $controllerMethod->getBy($request->active);
```

Comment: First method works fine. Second method also works fine if you don't have `Content-Type=application/json`, since it will use a json `ParameterBag` not the query one. I think this may actually be a bug, not 100% sure, regardless. This seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mergeIfMissing`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#merging-additional-input).

You can create your own custom middleware and put the below inside it or call the below inside the Controller's constructor(depending upon your design)

```
$request->mergeIfMissing(['active' => null /* or false */, 'ID' => -1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, we all agree that query params are string!

What you can do:

```php
getBy(Request $request){

   $request->boolean('active') // method returns true for 1, "1", true, "true", "on", and "yes". All other values will return false

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the parameter is not required unfortunately. Not having the parameter is going to cast the default value(null i think) to a boolean.

Comment: Right, you can add default value `$request->boolean('active', null)`

Comment: Doesn't work either, since you have a value by casting the null, so the default value is never actually used.

Comment: If value is passed, it will be a `boolean` , if value not passed the value will be `null` , so in all cases whatever you're doing after this instruction is working for you !

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that if you don't have a value in the query, doing `$result = $request->boolean('active', null);` will result in `false`, not null, since the underlying method uses `filter_var(null, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);` which results in `false`.

Comment: You are right, forgot about the filter .. then this will not work for you (especially in filter scopes)
Well, in that case what you suggest before or what the others suggest is the only way to achieve it.  (you can't run away from that extra code :D )

Answer (score 0):

you can create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware) for this and try [overwriting the parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#merging-additional-input):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CastAtiveToBool
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {

        $is_active = null;
        if ($request->get('active') === 1) {
            $is_active = true;
        } elseif ($request->get('active') === 0) {
            $is_active = false;
        }

        $request->merge(['active' => $is_active]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```